# Force html5 url input validator to allow blank scheme

Tags: html, forms, validation

I have the following input:

```
<input required type="url">
```

This forces users to add `http://` before they can submit a url. Is there anyway to get round that, without having to revert to an old-school text input?

I think it's quite common for people to enter `www.mysite.net`, and the browser validation bubble that pops up when a url is invalid does not mention that it is because the scheme is missing.

Comment: Why not have the `http://` in the box when the form loads?

Comment: ahh, that's a really good idea, js to the rescue

Comment: I've put it as an answer. There may be a solution using javascript that better fits your particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the `http://` in the input box when the form loads.

```
<input required type="url" value="http://" />
```

Probably not the answer you were looking for but it's a solution.

Comment: This is perfect, I was going to use JS, but now I see you can do it with the value attribute. You learn something new every day. Thanks.